# MicrosoftGraph Message API with filter returns "Unable to cast object of type"

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I need to filter all the mail messages with sender as valid email address. I tried the following API call

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=contains(from/emailAddress/address,'@')
```

It is returning the following error as response.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInternalServerError",
        "message": "Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.Types.RecipientConstantValueType' to type 'Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.Types.ConstantValueType'.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "c19c23f1-2be6-4bdd-9215-0ff1d43e48a8",
            "date": "2016-12-28T14:37:11"
        }
    }
}
```

Also I have tried the [substringof](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/csprd01/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-csprd01-part2-url-conventions.html#_Toc355091900) as follows

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=substringof('@',from/emailAddress/address)
```

The below is the response I got for the call

> *An unknown function with name 'substringof' was found. This may also be a function import or a key lookup on a navigation property, which
>   is not allowed.*

Please help on this issue or provide an alternate solution to filter messages with valid sender.

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail to your question, about the scenario where the user's mailbox can contain mail from an invalid sender, please?

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT It is not like an invalid sender, but some of the message response doesn't have from property and their toRecipient also empty. I thought it may be a internal notification message. I need to filter those messages.

Comment: Per the supported query parameters (https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/overview/query_parameters) I don't think the filters you are trying are supported.  You could use $search instead, but not sure whether this will work for your scenario.  I don't know whether $search supports any wildcards.

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT, Sorry, I couldn't use the $search for my call. I need to add date filter to my calls. As per documentation I can't combine $filter and $search in a single call. I have tried `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=from/emailAddress/address+ne+''` and `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=from/emailAddress/address+ne+null`. But both of them work incorrectly. Is there a way to filter records which have the from property?